# Graph automorphism group conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Let $G$ be the automorphism group on a graph $\Gamma(V,E)$. Why is it that group elements belonging to the same conjugacy class have the same cycle type? For example, if $a,b\in G$ are two automorphisms on $\Gamma$, such that $g^{-1}ag=b$ for some $g\in G$, then $a,b$ have the same cycle type?

Comment: This is a general fact about group actions, and has nothing in particular to do with graphs, other than the fact that graph automorphisms act on $V$ (or $E$).

Answer (score 1):

This is because $$\sigma (a_1\ \ldots \ a_n)(b_1\ \ldots \ b_k)\sigma^{-1}=\sigma (a_1\ \ldots \ a_n)\color{red}{\sigma^{-1}\sigma}(b_1\ \ldots \ b_k)\sigma^{-1}$$
and $$\sigma (a_1\ \ldots \ a_n)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a_1)\ \ldots \ \sigma(a_n))$$

Comment: sorry I'm not following. What are $(a_1...a_n)$ and $(b_1...b_k)$? are they arbitrary cycles of two group elements?

Comment: They are cycles in a cycle decomposition of a permutation. Note that it doesn't matter that $G$ is a group of automorphisms of a graph, your question holds more generally for any kind of permutations.